# Can anyone explain why each page request by LRU causes an I/O in sequential flooding?

Tags: database, memory-management, storage, lru

This may be a really simple question but I am having trouble understanding why each page request by LRU causes an I/O in sequential flooding. I understand the mechanisms of LRU and MRU but I just can't see why MRU is better when doing repeated scan of the file. I feel like in both cases, each scan results in one replacement of frame in the buffer pool?

Comment: Which DBMS are you talking about?

Comment: I am using SQL, but I think this is a general question on Buffer Pool that is used to bring pages from disk to the main memory.

Comment: "SQL" is a query language used by **all** relational DBMS. It is not a specific database product